# call database row in to a function

Tags: php, database, function

I am writing a function which is called into a page, but I am not sure how to call information form database into the function in order to use them. Basically I am doing some calculation in the function where I need information form database to do them.

Is there anyone who can give a clue on how ot do this? Many thanks F

*From a comment...*

> What I am trying to do is this: I have
>   a page in php which retieves some info
>   from database and all works fine. I am
>   writing a function that needs to make
>   some calculation based on some fields
>   in the database. What I cannot solve
>   is how to get this information form
>   the database into my function. I have
>   tired this: function CalculateCost ()
>   { $low_season =
>   $row_rsbooking['cost']; etc. etc. then
>   making some calculations but I am
>   getting nowhere. I am not sure if the
>   function is getting the information
>   form database in order to make
>   calculation.

Comment: Database?  Programming language?

Answer (score 1):

This is an older question, but as it remains unanswered, I will proffer my two cents.

From your comment to Rafael, it looks like your problem is variable scope. I think you want something like this

```
function add_one($cost) 
{ 
  // just something irrelevant to do
  return $cost + 1;
}

// query stuff here, leaving $row with the results
$new_value = add_one($row_rsbooking['cost']);
```

In other words, pass the column value you need to the function and process the results it returns. If you need to **alter** your actual row, you could pass the whole row by reference (i.e. `add_one(&$row)`) and modify it in your function.

Without some more code from you, this is my best guess.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the question. But will try to answer it the best way I can.

If you are looking for help on how to connect to a database and execute a query, then have a look at the following link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx

It describes how you can use the SQL Command object to get data from a SQL Server database in the form of a Dataset. Once this is done, you can get a dataset or datatable to get data to any function in your code for calculations.

You could also use an odbccommand. I would post a link, but I don't have enough reputation points to do more than one!  :o)

If the Dataset is too big, you could consider using a datable or a SQLDataReader. Again, please have a look at the MSDN for info on those classes.

I hope this helps!

Rafael Jovel
www.augensoftwaregroup.com

Comment: Thank you Rafael,

What I am trying to do is this:

I have a page in php which retieves some info from database and all works fine.

I am writing a function that needs to make some calculation based on some fields in the database. What I cannot solve is how to get this information form the database into my function.

I have tired this:

function CalculateCost ()
{

$low_season = $row_rsbooking['cost']; 
etc.
etc.

then making some calculations but I am getting nowhere.

I am not sure if the function is getting the information form database in order to make calculation. F